# Flask-GoogleMaps: are search and getCoordinates possible?

Tags: python, flask, google-maps-api-3, flask-wtforms

I am developing a web application with Python and Flask. For the front end I use Flask-WTF and Bootstrap.

I now work on the integration with Googlemaps. I've been experimenting for a while with Flask-GoogleMaps and have it working. I can display and manipulate maps on the web pages – so far so good.

Next step is being able to search for a location (just like on 'the real' googlemaps) to identify a location and retrieve the coordinates with a mouse click. I can't find any information / examples about that.

Therefore the following questions:
Is that indeed not possible?
And ...

- if it is possible: how, please give me a clue ....
- if it is not possible: which alternative approach can I best apply for my use case?

Answer (score 0):

The GoogleMaps API only gives you the ability to show a map and move around. To interact with the map further, you need to introduce other APIs from Google.

To implement a feature to search for places, you need to implement the [Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service). You will need to configure an API key for use with this API, but it should be free. Next, check out [these docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search) to implement the desired search tools to your web app.